# Django model structure

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I am creating a simple game database and I am having some problems.

There are 2 models: **Material** and **Building**.

```
class Material(Model):
    type = CharField(max_length=30)

class Building(Model):
    cost = M2M(?)
    input = M2M(?)
    output = M2M(?)
```

In the material model, material names are held (Wood, Stone, Iron, Plank, Fish, Food etc.).
Building should have a bit more fields, however, I encounter difficulties with these only. Imagine something like "The Settlers" game. The building demands 3 pieces of stone to be build (cost) and it takes 2 pieces of wood (input) to produce 1 plank (output).

How can I make such structure where I could specify the amount of material and easily modify it if necessary.

I have already tried to use through argument, however, it did not let me have 3 or more occurrences in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps your [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) table could have a `quantity` field?

**edit:**

ah, i see. this is a limitation due to the way through tables work. A through table only has references to the two models it's joining together, but can't know which fields on said models are defining the m2m relationship. So each through table may only be used for one relation. However, with some [abstract subclassing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) we can keep the code fairly clean:

```
class BuildingMaterialBase(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey('Material')
    building = models.ForeignKey('Building')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BuildingMaterialIn(BuildingMaterialBase):
    pass

class BuildingMaterialOut(BuildingMaterialBase):
    pass


class Building(models.Model):
    in_ = models.ManyToManyField(Material, through=BuildingMaterialIn)
    out_ = models.ManyToManyField(Material, through=BuildingMaterialOut)
```

Comment: Yes, it could, but it seems I cannot add more than 1 field relating through the same table in one model...

Comment: db.building: The model Building has two manually-defined m2m relations through the model ResourceQuantity, which is not permitted. Please consider using an extra field on your intermediary model instead.

Comment: By the way, how to create an instance of Building afterwards?